# jQuery validar caracteres em input

Tags: jquery, validação, input

Estou fazendo uma função ativada pelo onkeydown de input, que deve verificar os caracteres informados, um por um, e somente permitir a entrada no input dos que são válidos, isso deve acontecer antes dos caracteres serem mostrados no value do input.

Código

```
      var keyPressed = (e.key);
      var element = $(e.target);
      var elementSize = element.val().length;

      if(keyPressed.match(/^|[_.-]+/)){
          console.log("error");
          console.log(elementSize);
          var elementValNew = element.val().substring(0, elementSize -1);
          return element.val(elementValNew);
      else {
           console.log("Sucess");
           return true;
    }
```

Comment: pra facilitar, quais os caracteres que o campo não deve aceitar?

Comment: Tá aí no código... `/^|[_.-]+/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu faço essa validação realtime um pouco diferente, pego o evento, e faço a validação server-side.
Exemplo:

```
$(document).on('keyup change', '.input-field', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var type = $this.data('input-type');
    var value = $this.val();
    var data = {type: type, value: value};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "validate.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data)
        {

            if (data['status'] === 1) {
                $this.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                $this.closest('.form-group').find('.required').html("<i class='fa fa-check'></i>");
                $this.closest('.form-group').find('.required').removeClass('required').addClass('ok');
                $this.closest('.form-group').find('.ok').removeClass('symbol');
                $this.addClass('success');
            } else {
                $this.closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
                $this.closest('.form-group').find('.ok').removeClass('ok').addClass('required');
                $this.closest('.form-group').find('.required').addClass('symbol');
                $this.closest('.form-group').find('.required').html(data['msg']);
            }
            var a = 0;
            $this.closest('.tab-content').find('.form-control').each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('has-error')) {
                    a += 1;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Um exemplo de um input a ser validado:

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
<span class='required'>Nome:</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2 input-field" data-input-field="name" data-input-type="username">
</div>
```

Um exemplo de método validador usando a classe GUMP com algumas extensões:

```
public static function username($var, $field) {
        $is_valid = GUMP::is_valid($var, [
                    $field => 'against_sql_injection,1|alpha_dash|required|max_len,30|min_len,5',
        ]);
        if ($is_valid == 1) {
            $response['status'] = 1;
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 0;
            $response['msg'] = $is_valid[0];
        }
        $response['field'] = $field;
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui encontrar a solução para impedir que os caracteres não desejados não sejam nem adicionados ao input foi adicionar: event.preventDefault e event.stopPropagation na função, no lugar do returno false;